# Python Django init.py

Tags: python, django, pycharm

Here is the errors I am facing. I tried many things but it does not work.
First the project was run, after that it is not running.

[image]

The code is below:

```
 """
    Settings and configuration for Django.
    
    Read values from the module specified by the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE environment
    variable, and then from django.conf.global_settings; see the global_settings.py
    for a list of all possible variables.
    """
    
    import importlib
    import os
    import time
    import traceback
    import warnings
    from pathlib import Path
    
    import django
    from django.conf import global_settings
    from django.core.exceptions import ImproperlyConfigured
    from django.utils.deprecation import RemovedInDjango40Warning
    from django.utils.functional import LazyObject, empty
    
    ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE = "DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"
    
    PASSWORD_RESET_TIMEOUT_DAYS_DEPRECATED_MSG = (
        'The PASSWORD_RESET_TIMEOUT_DAYS setting is deprecated. Use '
        'PASSWORD_RESET_TIMEOUT instead.'
    )
    
    DEFAULT_HASHING_ALGORITHM_DEPRECATED_MSG = (
        'The DEFAULT_HASHING_ALGORITHM transitional setting is deprecated. '
        'Support for it and tokens, cookies, sessions, and signatures that use '
        'SHA-1 hashing algorithm will be removed in Django 4.0.'
    )
    
    
    class SettingsReference(str):
        """
        String subclass which references a current settings value. It's treated as
        the value in memory but serializes to a settings.NAME attribute reference.
        """
        def __new__(self, value, setting_name):
            return str.__new__(self, value)
    
        def __init__(self, value, setting_name):
            self.setting_name = setting_name
    
    
    class LazySettings(LazyObject):
        """
        A lazy proxy for either global Django settings or a custom settings object.
        The user can manually configure settings prior to using them. Otherwise,
        Django uses the settings module pointed to by DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE.
        """
        def _setup(self, name=None):
            """
            Load the settings module pointed to by the environment variable. This
            is used the first time settings are needed, if the user hasn't
            configured settings manually.
            """
            settings_module = os.environ.get(ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE)
            if not settings_module:
                desc = ("setting %s" % name) if name else "settings"
                raise ImproperlyConfigured(
                    "Requested %s, but settings are not configured. "
                    "You must either define the environment variable %s "
          "or call settings.configure() before accessing settings."
         %(desc, ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE_django)
    
        self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
        def __repr__(self):
                # Hardcode the class name as otherwise it yields 'Settings'.
                if self._wrapped is empty:
                    return '<LazySettings [Unevaluated]>'
                return '<LazySettings "%(settings_module)s">' %{
        'settings_module': self._wrapped.SETTINGS_MODULE
                    }
    def __getattr__(self, name):
            """Return the value of a setting and cache it in self.__dict__."""
            if self._wrapped is empty:
                self._setup(name)
            val = getattr(self._wrapped, name)
            self.__dict__[name] = val
    returnvalue
    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
            """
            Set the value of setting. Clear all cached values if _wrapped changes
            (@override_settings does this) or clear single values when set.
            """
            if name == '_wrapped':
                self.__dict__.clear()
            else:
             self.__dict__.pop(name,None)                           
    
    super().__setattr__  (name, value)
    
        def __delattr__(self, name):
    
            """Delete a setting and clear it from cache if needed."""
            super().__delattr__(name)
    
            self.__dict__.pop(name, None)
    
        def configure(self, default_settings=global_settings, **options):
            """
            Called to manually configure the settings. The 'default_settings'
            parameter sets where to retrieve any unspecified values from (its
            argument must support attribute access (__getattr__)).
            """
            if self._wrapped is not empty:
                raise RuntimeError('Settings already configured.')
            holder = UserSettingsHolder(default_settings)
            for name, value in options.items():
                if not name.isupper():
                    raise TypeError\
                        ('Setting %r must be uppercase.' % name)
                setattr(holder, name, value)
            self._wrapped = holder
    
            @staticmethod
        def _add_script_prefix(value):
            """
            Add SCRIPT_NAME prefix to relative paths.
    
            Useful when the app is being served at a subpath and manually prefixing
            subpath to STATIC_URL and MEDIA_URL in settings is inconvenient.
            """
        

        # Don't apply prefix to absolute paths and URLs.
        if value.startswith(('http://', 'https://', '/')):
            return value
        from django.urls import get_script_prefix
        return '%s%s' % (get_script_prefix(), value)

    @property
    def configured(self):
        """Return True if the settings have already been configured."""
        return self._wrapped is not empty

    @property
    def PASSWORD_RESET_TIMEOUT_DAYS(self):
        stack = traceback.extract_stack()
        # Show a warning if the setting is used outside of Django.
        # Stack index: -1 this line, -2 the caller.
        filename, _, _, _ = stack[-2]
        if not filename.startswith(os.path.dirname(django.__file__)):
            warnings.warn(
                PASSWORD_RESET_TIMEOUT_DAYS_DEPRECATED_MSG,
                RemovedInDjango40Warning,
                stacklevel=2,
            )
        return self.__getattr__('PASSWORD_RESET_TIMEOUT_DAYS')

    @property
    def static_url (self):
        return self._add_script_prefix(self.__getattr__('STATIC_URL'))

    @property
    def media_url (self):
        return self._add_script_prefix\

    (self.__getattr__('MEDIA_URL'))

class Settings:
    def __init__(self, settings_module):
        # update this dict from global settings (but only for ALL_CAPS settings)
        for setting in dir(global_settings):
            if setting.isupper():
                setattr(self, setting, getattr(global_settings, setting))

        # store the settings module in case someone later cares
        self.SETTINGS_MODULE = settings_module

        mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)

        tuple_settings = (
            "INSTALLED_APPS",
            "TEMPLATE_DIRS",
            "LOCALE_PATHS",
        )
        self._explicit_settings = set()
        for setting in dir(mod):
            if setting.isupper():
                setting_value = getattr(mod, setting)

                if (setting in tuple_settings and
                        not isinstance(setting_value, (list, tuple))):
                    raise ImproperlyConfigured("The %s setting must be a list or a tuple. " % setting)
                setattr(self, setting, setting_value)
                self._explicit_settings.add(setting)
    
            if not self.SECRET_KEY:
                raise ImproperlyConfigured("The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.")
    
            if self.is_overridden('PASSWORD_RESET_TIMEOUT_DAYS'):
                if self.is_overridden('PASSWORD_RESET_TIMEOUT'):
                    raise ImproperlyConfigured(
                        'PASSWORD_RESET_TIMEOUT_DAYS/PASSWORD_RESET_TIMEOUT are '
                        'mutually exclusive.'
                    )
                setattr(self, 'PASSWORD_RESET_TIMEOUT', self.PASSWORD_RESET_TIMEOUT_DAYS * 60 * 60 * 24)
                warnings.warn(PASSWORD_RESET_TIMEOUT_DAYS_DEPRECATED_MSG, RemovedInDjango40Warning)
    
            if self.is_overridden('DEFAULT_HASHING_ALGORITHM'):
                warnings.warn(DEFAULT_HASHING_ALGORITHM_DEPRECATED_MSG, RemovedInDjango40Warning)
    
            if hasattr(time, 'tzset') and self.TIME_ZONE:
                # When we can, attempt to validate the timezone. If we can't find
                # this file, no check happens and it's harmless.
                zoneinfo_root = Path('/usr/share/zoneinfo')
                zone_info_file = zoneinfo_root.joinpath(*self.TIME_ZONE.split('/'))
                if zoneinfo_root.exists() and not zone_info_file.exists():
                    raise ValueError("Incorrect timezone setting: %s" % self.TIME_ZONE)
                # Move the time zone info into os.environ. See ticket #2315 for why
                # we don't do this unconditionally (breaks Windows).
                os.environ['TZ'] = self.TIME_ZONE
                time.tzset()
    
        def is_overridden(self, setting):
            return setting in self._explicit_settings
    
        def __repr__(self):
            return '<%(cls)s "%(settings_module)s">' % {
                'cls': self.__class__.__name__,
                'settings_module': self.SETTINGS_MODULE,
            }
    
    
    class UserSettingsHolder:
        """Holder for user configured settings."""
        # SETTINGS_MODULE doesn't make much sense in the manually configured
        # (standalone) case.
        SETTINGS_MODULE = None
    
        def __init__(self, default_settings):
            """
            Requests for configuration variables not in this class are satisfied
            from the module specified in default_settings (if possible).
            """
            self.__dict__['_deleted'] = set()
            self.default_settings = default_settings
    
        def __getattr__(self, name):
            if not name.isupper() or name in self._deleted:
                raise AttributeError
            return getattr(self.default_settings, name)
    
        def __setattr__(self, name, value):
            self._deleted.discard(name)
            if name == 'PASSWORD_RESET_TIMEOUT_DAYS':
                setattr(self, 'PASSWORD_RESET_TIMEOUT', value * 60 * 60 * 24)
                warnings.warn(PASSWORD_RESET_TIMEOUT_DAYS_DEPRECATED_MSG, RemovedInDjango40Warning)
            if name == 'DEFAULT_HASHING_ALGORITHM':
                warnings.warn(DEFAULT_HASHING_ALGORITHM_DEPRECATED_MSG, RemovedInDjango40Warning)
            super().__setattr__(name, value)
    
        def __delattr__(self, name):
            self._deleted.add(name)
            if hasattr(self, name):
                super().__delattr__(name)
    
        def __dir__(self):
            return sorted(
                s for s in [*self.__dict__, *dir(self.default_settings)]
                if s not in self._deleted
            )
    
        def is_overridden(self, setting):
       

        deleted = (setting in self._deleted)
        set_locally = (setting in self.__dict__)
        set_on_default = getattr(self.default_settings, 'is_overridden', lambda s: False)(setting)
        return deleted or set_locally or set_on_default

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<%(cls)s>' % {
            'cls': self.__class__.__name__,
        }


settings = `LazySettings()`
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please don't post images of code or errors, use plain text. Your indentation is off, and that's what your errors tell you as well. Python uses indent to for code structure. Check the error lines your IDE mentions, and use a Python text book or tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the exception (and the code), you have (or something has) somehow irrevocably messed up the `django/conf/settings.py` module's contents.

There is never a need to touch the Django package under `site-packages` itself.

Uninstall and reinstall Django:

Use

```
pip freeze -l
```

to find out which version of Django you'd currently have (e.g `Django==3.1`).

Then uninstall Django:

```
pip uninstall -y Django
```

Then reinstall the same version of Django, e.g.:

```
pip install Django==3.1
```